# Python matplotlib saving figures

Tags: python, matplotlib, remote-access, figure, savefiledialog

I am not sure if I could describe this situation clearly, but let's say I have a function imported from a library:

```
from somelib import somefunc
somefunc(someinputs)
```

If I run this code on my local machine, a figure would pop up and pause the code until I manually close it.  For some reason I cannot run it on my local machine so I had to run it remotely via ssh session.  In this case the figure doesn't pop up anymore, I wanted to find a way to save this figure as png file and so I could download it from my remote machine to see it.  I cannot modify the source files of this library.  Anyone could give me some suggestions?  Thanks you!

Comment: Definitely not the best solution, but you can do ssh -X to run graphic applications remotely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use multiple ways depending upon your image..

```
from PIL import Image  
import PIL  

# creating a image object (main image)  
im1 = Image.open(r"C:\Users\System-Pc\Desktop\flower1.jpg")  

# save a image using extension 
im1 = im1.save("new.jpg")
```

using matplotlib

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.savefig('new.png')
```